# Python Pyrogram handle poll answers from users

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I've sent a poll using Pyrogram but i don't know how to get users answers!

For example:
the quiz has 4 answers one of them is correct when the user press one of the answers i want to get what they pressed, here my code:

```
@app.on_message(filters.private & filters.text)
async def reply_message(client, message):

    quiz() #function returns global vars, question, answers, answerID
    
    await app.send_poll(chat_id=message.chat.id, question=question, options=answers, is_anonymous=False, type="quiz", correct_option_id=answerID)
```